# is it allowed to call [obj copy] in ObjC with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, copy, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

There's one thing I don't understand regarding ARC: how should we now treat local variables that were created using `[... copy]`? If I make a property with `(copy)` flag, ARC will handle this automatically, but as far as I know there's no `__copy` flag for variables.

I've tested this with such code:

```
@interface Foo : NSString
@end

@implementation Foo

- (void) dealloc {
  NSLog(@"%p deallocated", self);
}

- (NSUInteger) length {
  return 1;
}

- (unichar) characterAtIndex: (NSUInteger) i {
  return 'x';
}

@end

- (void) foo {
  Foo *f = [[Foo alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"%p", f);

  Foo *f2 = [f copy];
  NSLog(@"%p", f2);
}
```

What I get is:

```
0x102406530
0x102015f10
0x102406530 deallocated
```

I never get "0x102015f10 deallocated", which would suggest the copied variable doesn't get released. It doesn't even get autoreleased, because when I made another method `[Foo foo]` that returned an autoreleased object, I did get a "deallocated" message a moment later.

So is there any way I can cause it to be released without converting it to a property?

Comment: If you was going to do this experimentation then you would be better off working with a class where you fully understand the memory management. `NSString` has who knows what memory optimisations so it doesn't give you a good base to play with. Also `NSString` is part of a class cluster and inheriting is not as simple as you have done, there are a lot more hoops you need to jump through.

Comment: @Paul.s So you're British, right? I didn't know there existed 'you was'. What's this construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my bad - ARC does actually handle copied objects properly. I got wrong results because of using NSString for the test, because I wanted to use a class that already implemented copying instead of implementing it explicitly; when I repeated the test on a class inheriting from NSObject and implementing `copyWithZone:` by returning `[[Foo alloc] init]`, I got two "deallocated" messages. Thanks to @Paul.s for pointing that out.

Comment: I guess under ARC, `copy` returns an object with a reference count of 1, then when you assign it to a strong reference, it isn't retained again, had the compiler noticed the object was created by copying another one.

Comment: Actually, ARC does handle copied object properly. And you can subclass NSString, but the documentation states that there are methods you must override, including, among others, the implementations of `NSCopying`